# Software Rendering on Lubuntu

Tags: drivers, graphics, lubuntu

I'm trying to resurrect an old laptop with Lubuntu, it's a Lenovo Thinkpad X100e.

I think I'm having issues because the laptop is software rendering rather than using the gpu. When I have started a light game on the pc it has popped up with the warning that the computer is using software rendering.

Whenever anything slightly heavy, for example editing a document in google drive, needs to be rendered the laptop slows down a lot, with CPU maxing out. It also seems a lot hotter than it should be.

To see if I have the correct driver installed I've run

```
lscpi
```

which amongst other info returns

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780M [Mobility Radeon HD 3200]
```

From what I've read the Radeon driver is the one I should be using.

Can anyone tell me whether the laptop is in fact running software rendering and how to fix?

Thanks

**edit**

Cheers for the help, I hadn't thought to alter the swappiness.

I have changed the swappiness to 10, and it does seem to be running better, however still not processing even basic graphics very well.

Would changing swappiness help CPU? I thought it would only help my RAM, which doesn't seem to ever go over 1000MB out of 1700MB available.

Maybe this is just the best I can get out of this laptop, but I thought I would be able to browse websites easily with it.

```
glxinfo |grep version
```

returns

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.2.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 17.2.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

Comment: Can you say what game? Also are you sure you are not ending up swapping which causes a massive slowdown as editing in google drive uses more ram then say aviword. One reason I could see it giong back to software rendering is not a new enough opengl version on your drivers and your inbuilt graphics. Can you edit your question with glxinfo |grep version

Comment: @ianorlin does this tell you whether the laptop is utilising the GPU or not? Thanks